# How to deal with CodeIgniter Error Number 1064?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a login system and I'm getting this database error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `last_activity` = 1467333267, `user_data` = 'a:3:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1
>
> UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1467333267, `user_data` = 'a:3:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"email\";s:16:\"ocyl28@yahoo.com\";s:12:\"is_logged_in\";i:1;}' WHERE `session_id` = '570d7ba3d7f11a9a35264ed276368480'
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Here is my controller code:

```
class Template extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->login();
    }   

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('Login Template.php');
    }

    public function admin()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
            $this->load->view('Template 3.php');    
        }
        else {
            echo 'cannot login';
        }   
    }

    public function login_validation()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email' , 'Email', 'required|trim|callback_validate_credentials');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' , 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data = array (
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'is_logged_in' => 1
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('template/admin');
        }
        else 
        {

            echo 'fail';
        }

    }

    public function validate_credentials()
    {
        $this->load->model('users');

        if ($this->users->can_log_in()) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials', 'fail to login');
            return false;
        }
    }



    public function about()
    {
        $this->load->view('About this site.php');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('template/login');
    }
```

And here is my model code:

```
class Users extends CI_Model
{

    public function can_log_in()
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));

        $query = $this->db->get('registered_users');

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return true; 
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Table name is missing from your SQL statement.

Comment: can you show me how to do it. i'm just new to SQL and php